# Casablanca: Assigning a Variable to a JSON Table Value

Tags: c++, json, casablanca

This is probably a simple question, but I have no idea as to the answer. I've tried googling it, but I don't know what to google. I need to assign a variable to a JSON table value (username string to username table value). I saw an example on MSDN with something like this:

```
 obj2[L"password"] = json::value::string(U("password"));
```

However, if I remove the quotations and put in the variable name, it errors. I have a feeling this has to do with the "U". However, I honestly have no idea what that "U" is called (an iterator?) or how to change it. Could you help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find a solution to this problem after some searching and creative problem solving. There is little documentation on this issue, however, I did determine that the U is called a macro--in Casablanca it converts (almost) any type of string into a "utility::string_t" form. It does this literally, not accepting variables.

In order to solve this problem, I just declared 'password' and 'username' as:

```
 utility::string_t password
 utility::string_t username
```

And then worked with them as normal. Hope this helps anyone with the same issue out!

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem that you have. I tried your solution, but I could not make this to work:

```
utility::string_t text = "value1"; //no suitable constructor exists from     const char to basic string
```

So looking for others method I found that this also works:

```
auto text = U("value1");
```

after that the assignment works too:

```
answer[L"key1"] = web::json::value::string(text);
```